# How to use TensorFlow in R if I have Anaconda Python already installed?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, anaconda

In the [guide about using TensorFlow](https://rstudio.github.io/tensorflow/) in R, they suggest not to use the Anaconda TensorFlow installation. Does this mean Anaconda Python cannot coexist with using TensorFlow in R?

Comment: hi my problem is that can I use it with R?

Comment: I installed tensorflow via anaconda and it works fine with the tensorflow package in R

Comment: that's great to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer an issue, the documentation was updated too.

See here: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/commit/4e1e11d6ba2fe7efe1a03356f96172dbf8db365e

Comment: @BhargavRao: I flagged the other question as a duplicate because this one here was earlier.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue using anaconda along with R. Please follow [this](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow) link for more info.

Directly from the link above:

TensorFlow for R is currently only compatible with OS X and Linux (support for Windows will likely be added over the next few months).

You should NOT install TensorFlow with Anaconda as there are issues with the way Anaconda builds the python shared library that prevent dynamic linking from R. There are potential solution to the above problem see [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/498) for more details.

Comment: So my question is that whether I can have anoconda python installed for other use and at the same time let R call the default Python? if so, how can I do that?

Comment: you can have `anaconda` running up with R but there seems to be some issue with linking python libraries, so the `pip` way of installing in preferred.

Comment: As of now, we need to install 64 bit Python 3.5 or 3.6. Anaconda Python is recommended.