# How to install Tensorflow for R

Tags: r, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I had Tensorflow installed with Anaconda. Now I want use it in R and I need to reinstall Tensorflow, because the note [here](https://rstudio.github.io/tensorflow)

> NOTE: You should NOT install TensorFlow with Anaconda as there are
>   issues with the way Anaconda builds the python shared library that
>   prevent dynamic linking from R.

I already tried to uninstall from Anaconda and install with pip but its came to the same place in anaconda directory. Tesorflow is working from terminal but in R shows `Error: Command failed (1)`

Anybody can help me to how I can solve the problem? Should I uninstall anaconda and install Tensorflow using pip?

Comment: I wonder if installing inside a virtual environment would do it. That way, the install would be isolated from anaconda and accessible from R. Also, have you modified your PATH which should now point to the pip installed destination (and not within /anaconda)?

Comment: Thank you Roman, it is may be idea use with Docker, and give a path to R to acces it. But I would try your second advice first.I just don't know how to modify PATH for pip install Tensorflow without anaconda, I mean isolated. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use TensorFlow in R if I have Anaconda Python already installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560982/how-to-use-tensorflow-in-r-if-i-have-anaconda-python-already-installed)

Comment: R in Anaconda will not connect with R outside of Anaconda, as well as Python. Different environment and different installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options on what to do. Probably the cleanest one is to install a system-wide python (if not installed yet) and then create a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). This basically takes your system python binaries and moves them to its own compartment where everythign is isolated from the rest, incl. anaconda. Once you are inside an activated virtual environment you can install all the necessary Python appendages for TensorFlow. Once that is done, make sure you set up a correct environmental PATH for TensorFlow from where R can reach it:

```
Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/path/to/virtualenv/python/binary")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
```

Example of the path to where you installed the virtual environment project would be, I think, something like `~/minion/medvedi/venv_medvedi/bin/python`.

Comment: I did install Python though the brew and  instal vertualenv, and inside of vertualenv pip install python and then tensorflow. Everything working, I tested TF. But inside of R studio its still the same problem :(  I get the path of location of TF in  "sudo pip shoe tensorflow"  and copy path to R in `Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/Users/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-package")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")`
unfortunately, R studio gave me the same mistake :( 
`ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘tensorflow’
* removing " .../tensorflow"
Error: Command failed (1)`

Comment: @IrinaMax you need to link to the python binary, not where the Python packages reside (I've edited what the path should look like on linux/Debian).

Comment: I found my PATH as :  python -c "import os; print(os.environ['_'])"

Comment: Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/usr/local/bin/python"), i installed python 2.7, now show: An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/irinamahmudjanova/Library/R/3.3/library/tensorflow’
Error: Command failed (1)

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue, the documentation was updated too.

See here:
https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/commit/4e1e11d6ba2fe7efe1a03356f96172dbf8db365e

Comment: As long as this question is not confirmed as a duplicate I think this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Keras, we can install the TensorFlow package in R.

```
install_keras()
library(keras)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
install_tensorflow(package_url = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/b8/d6/af3d52dd52150ec4a6ceb7788bfeb2f62ecb6aa2d1172211c4db39b349a2/tensorflow-1.3.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=1cf77a2360ae2e38dd3578618eacc03b")
library(tensorflow)
```

> Keras is a high-level neural network API for deep learning from TensorFlow Google.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the best and fast method to do it in R:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
install_keras(method = "conda")
install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")
tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to install anaconda and create an environment called "r-reticulate".

you can do it using anaconda navigator or

```
reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-reticulate")
```

then to check that env detected by reticulate, use `reticulate::conda_python()`.it must return directory of python.exe for your env.
after that you can install tensorflow by `install_tensorflow()`. [not working in my case]

so I install the tesnorflow from CMD.
follow these steps:

1. open the cmd :]
2. activate the `r-reticulate` env using `conda activate r-reticulate` (you may need your directory to conda directory if you did not add conda to your PATH)
3. use : `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow`

now in R, you can use TensorFlow.
for installing Keras, you can use `pip install Keras`. [i tried install_keras() function after the installation of tensorflow, but it ruined my TensorFlow installation also]